# Problem connecting to a SOAP API in password protected directory

Tags: php, magento, soap, iis-7.5

I am trying to access a Magento API, using SOAP. the code I have works fine normally, however the client wishes to password protect the Magento main folder. Doing so breaks access to the API and causes an error.

The documentation suggests this isnt a problem and you can just specify the username/password, however this does not work.

I am using PHP and IIS, with the password protection set up via Plesk 10. Does this use Basic HTTP authentication or something else?

My access code is:

```
$client = new SoapAuthClient($GLOBALS["magento_api_path"],array(  

                            'login'=>"admin", 
                            'password'=>"password" 
                          ) 
                    ); 
$session = $client->login($GLOBALS["magento_api_user"], $GLOABLS["magento_api_password"] ,
                    array(  

                            'login'=>"admin", 
                            'password'=>"password" 
                          ) );
```

The error I get is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.domain.co.uk/magento/index.php/api/index/index/wsdl/1/' : failed to load external entity "http://www.domain.co.uk/magento/index.php/api/index/index/wsdl/1/" in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.co.uk\httpdocs\backend\index.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.co.uk\httpdocs\backend\index.php(20): SoapClient->__call('login', Array) #1 C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.co.uk\httpdocs\backend\index.php(20): SoapClient->login('backenduser', 'backendwebuser', Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\domain.co.uk\httpdocs\backend\index.php on line 20
```

The line referred to is the $client->login command.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of Magento are you running?  I ask because, looking at the code, 1.4.2+ shouldn't have the callback authentication problem any more.

Comment: I had this problem when accessing the Magento SOAP API from Java. The code failed with a '401: Unauthorized' error. Reading the OP I realised that the development site that I was trying to access was password protected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is likely because internally Magento is requesting, via a local HTTP request, it's own WSDL.  As you've password protected the access, it's not going to work.  Modify the security to not require a password if the request is coming from localhost.

Comment: Or, add an exception for the WSDL URL.

Comment: Can you advise how to do this on IIS using Plesk? I do no not have any options other than to put a password on the directory, i cannot see anywhere to add exceptions?

Comment: Unfortunatly not. Sorry.  But I would bet money that if you open the WSDL's URL it will work.  I think they use an internal HTTP request so they get a fully parsed WSDL.

Comment: yes, accessing the WSDL directly works fine. I think this is the problem, all I need now is a solution. How can I add an exception, or add authentication to the internal HTTP request?

Comment: I suggest splitting this off to a new question.  It's a basic IIS and/or Plesk admin question best suited for ServerFault.  As to the error you are getting, the answer I provided is to tell you what is causing the error.

Answer (score 8):

I've faced a similiar problem long time ago.

In my case, I didn't immediately realize that I need to use `.htaccess` credentials while creating the `SoapClient` instance, but pass SOAP API credentials to the `login` method.

I was passing the SOAP API credentials all over and got a similiar error like you do.

Here's what worked for me (1.3.x version, though. Still works for me as of today):

```
$cProxy = new SoapClient(
    URL . 'index.php/api/soap/?wsdl',
    array(
        'login' => HTACCESS_USER,
        'password' => HTACCESS_PASS
    )
);
$rSessionId = $cProxy->login(
    SOAP_USER,
    SOAP_PASS
);
```

Just to play save, that you are didn't got trapped by a typo: you pass `$GLOABLS["magento_api_password"]` as 2nd param to the `login` method, which should be `$GLOBALS["magento_api_password"]`.

Finally, you're passing a 3rd argument to the `login` method which I believe is obsolete, since afaik it's defined to have two params only:

```
<message name="login">
    <part name="username" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="apiKey" type="xsd:string" />
</message>
```

Comment: Your answer does not address the stated problem. You are solving for the initial access needing HTTP AUTH info. The problem is that Magento makes an internal call back to itself to get the parsed WSDL. If your web server is configured to require HTTP AUTH on this internal request then it was failing.

Answer (score 4):

Been there, done that :P

```
    $client = new SoapClient("http://${http_user}:${http_pass}@subdomain.domain.com", array(
        'login' => $user,
        'password' => $pass,
    ));
```

The problem is that the use of the http auth only happens during the requests and not while actually fetching the wsdl on the first request. To get around that, simply use the format i posted above: http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@server.com/

Cheers

Comment: this does not appear to work either - I still get the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `Mage_Api_Model_Server_Adapter_Soap::getWsdlUrl()` you will see, that magento assumes that basic auth login and password are passed as environment variables `PHP_AUTH_USER` and `PHP_AUTH_PW`.